# sre_constants.error: unexpected end of regular expression - Should Work Fine

Tags: python, regex, runtime-error

So I'm doing a little bit of testing for something and I require a method of splitting a string into groups of two. (e.g. `'abcdef' => ['ab','cd','ef']`)

I'm trying to use a regex pattern to do this (`[^]{2}`). Whenever I try to compile this pattern, I get the error message:

> sre_constants.error: unexpected end of regular expression

The exact line of code is:
`pat = re.compile(r'[^]{2}')`

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here? I've done a lot of searching but a lot of the problems were related to incorrect usage and/or backslashes.

I thought about it possibly being because of string formatting, though the Python docs didn't mention anything about any issues.

Comment: Why do you want to use regular expressions for this?

Comment: In python (and other languages) you can use an ascii string like an array. `'abcdef'[0:2]` returns `ab` for example.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
(.{2})
```

Dot will match any character. If you want to match newline characters with dot do not forget to add `s` modifier. So your code will look like this

```
p = re.compile('(?s)(.{2})')
```

Also I am not sure why you want to use regular expressions for the task. You can do it with following snippet

```
In [5]: line = 'abcdef'

In [6]: n = 2

In [7]: [line[i:i+n] for i in xrange(0, len(line), n)]
Out[7]: ['ab', 'cd', 'ef']
```

Comment: Except newlines. I want newlines.

Comment: what do you mean? you want to split string `abc\n` into `ab` ,`c\n`?

Comment: Yes. Also, regex is a lot simpler than that snippet.

Comment: @Spedwards: using regex has a cost, and this method that is simple too (and pythonic) avoids this cost. Note that it can be written like a one liner.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that in JavaScript `[^]` means "match any character" (though even [regex101 says](https://regex101.com/r/wQ5eI4/1): *"Note: Avoid this construct, use . or **[\s\S]** instead.")*. However, in Python, `[^]` is an invalid character class (see [this example](https://regex101.com/r/fY0vZ9/2) on regex101).

Use `(?s)(.{2})`.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fY0vZ9/3).

`(?s)` inline option will make sure you also match the newline characters.

Comment: It seems weird to me that `[^]` is invalid in Python. I swear I've used it before and it worked fine.

Comment: Have a look at http://goo.gl/uKQenL, the program is not compiling. Python is looking for some characters inside the character class, but does not find them, so it fails.